# SOLVED - Swift Enum - Casting Nested Enums to String Enum to allow .rawValue

Tags: swift, string, enums, nested, return-value

### SOLVED

Thank you @New Dev and @Joakim Danielson for your help. I used @Joakim Danielson's answer to improve my code.

I have an extension method to assign accessibilityIdentifiers to views based on a given String Enum. I updated the method to directly accept String Enum Cases as a parameter, thus COMPLETELY eliminating the need for the AccessibilityId enum class as shown below, awesome!

#### Changes

Before:

```
.accessibility(identifier: .home(.clickButton))

// Simplified for StackOverflow.
// Imagine 20 more cases..
enum AccessibilityId { 
    case home(HomeId)
    
    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .home(let id):
            return id.rawValue
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func accessibility(identifier: AccessibilityId) -> ModifiedContent<Self, AccessibilityAttachmentModifier> {
        self.accessibility(identifier: identifier.rawValue)
    }
}
```

After:

```
.accessibility(identifier: HomeId.clickButton)

extension View {    
    func accessibility<T: RawRepresentable>(identifier: T) -> ModifiedContent<Self, AccessibilityAttachmentModifier> where T.RawValue == String {
        self.accessibility(identifier: identifier.rawValue)
    }
}
```

---------------------------------------------------------------

## Original Question

### What I have

```
enum Item {
    case animal(AnimalId)
    case vehicle(VehicleId)
    case food(FoodId)
    
    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .animal(let id):
            return id.rawValue
        case .vehicle(let id):
            return id.rawValue
        case .food(let id):
            return id.rawValue
        }
    }
}

enum AnimalId: String {
    case cat
    case dog
}

// etc.
// Imagine more cases and more enums.
```

### What I want

```
enum Item {
    case animal(AnimalId)
    case vehicle(VehicleId)
    case food(FoodId)
    
    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case self as StringEnum:
            return id.rawValue
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
func test() {
   foo(.animal(.cat))
   foo(.vehicle(.plane))
   foo(.food(.tacos))
}

func foo(_ item: Item) {
   print(item.rawValue)
}
```

I am happy with the usage, but I'd like to reduce the amount of duplicate cases in the given switch statement. Notice how they all have `return id.rawValue`. The above is just an example, in reality I have around 30 cases.

### My Question

Is there a way for me to catch all Nested String Enums in a single switch or let case to reduce the duplicate code I have to write without losing the intended usage?

Thank you for your efforts, I hope to find an improvement for my code!

Comment: So Animal and AnimalId is the same thing?

Comment: What are the definitions on `AnimalId` and such?

Comment: Ah yes @JoakimDanielson! My bad, I've edited my question, thanks!

Comment: @Alexander AnimalId, VehicleId and FoodId are all String Enums with simple cases like "case cat, case dog, case car, case fruit" anything you can imagine, no other variables or methods involved for the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that is not based on Item being an enum but instead a generic struct

```
struct Item<T: RawRepresentable> where T.RawValue == String {
    let thing: T

    var rawValue: String {
        thing.rawValue
    }
}
```

With this solution you don't need to change your other enums.
Example

```
let item1 = Item(thing: AnimalId.cat)
let item2 = Item(thing: VehicleId.car)
print(item1.rawValue, item2.rawValue)
```

outputs

> cat car

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, based on that, I've managed to find a solution for my needs. I've updated my question / post to reflect my changes! I've accepted your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need something common between all these associated values, like a conformance to a shared protocol, e.g. `protocol RawStringValue`:

```
protocol RawStringValue {
   var rawValue: String { get }
}

// String enums already conform without any extra implementation
extension AnimalId: RawStringValue {} 
extension VehicleId: RawStringValue {}
extension FoodId: RawStringValue {}
```

Then you could create a `switch self` inside  like so:

```
var rawValue: String {
   switch self {
   case .animal  (let id as RawStringValue),
        .vehicle (let id as RawStringValue),
        .food    (let id as RawStringValue):
      return id.rawValue
   }
}
```

That being said, enum with associated values isn't the most convenient type to work with, so be sure that it's the right choice.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Good to see auto-conformance to RawStringValue, that's nice. And I'm happy to see it's possible to let cases fall through by casting them to the same protocol! But I'm not satisfied just yet.

Is there a type or class a String Enum can be cast to without introducing a protocol?